# How to find newly added item in the sharepoint portal?

Tags: object-model, list

How to find the recently added item in the share point page

If the any user added the items in the custom list, library, list,Announcement, Picture library,etc.........

i need to show all item that added last 2 days. Is that any object model available to find all item in the share point site???Instead of searching every list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use the SPWeb.GetChanges method which queries the change log and returns a collection of changes that have occurred in the Web site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getchanges.aspx

You can further drill down this detial at the list or item level and even get changes in a specific duration.

Comment: here is an working example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439213.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SPSiteDataQuery or maybe even ContentByQueryWebPart?

Apply a filter on Created field.

Comment: I agree that the CQWP (Content Query Web Part) would seem to be a good out-of-the-box first choice for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the search API to find all list items and filter where the creation date is greater than or equal to today minus two days.